# Sequelize - Change Date column to without milliseconds

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

Let's say I have a column called `createdAt` that I spun up on a model and it now displays `2018-06-08 20:25:46.184-05` (`Y-m-d H:i:s.u`) on the Postgres database. But I want to truncate that to `2018-06-08 20:25:46` (`Y-m-d H:i:s`). I am doing this so `Laravel` will play nicely with this `Sequelized database`.

Current Input: `2018-06-08 20:25:46.184-05`
Desired Output: `2018-06-08 20:25:46`

I am looking at the docs (http://docs.sequelizejs.com/variable/index.html) but I cannot see where I can turn my `createdAt` column to date (Without timezone)

Here what I have so far for `20180618004714-remove-timezone-from-timestamp.js`:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface
    .changeColumn('Users', 'createdAt', {
      type: Sequelize.DATE(),
      allowNull: false
    });
  },

  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    //
  }
};
```

Comment: Can you clearly mention your **Input** and expected **output** (I think this is expected output `2018-06-08 20:25:46`)?

Comment: Done. I forgot to add the milliseconds @VicJordan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve this but one simplest way to convert date/timestamp into desired format is via [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/).

Below is working example of it:

```js
var input = moment("2018-06-08 20:25:46.184-05").format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
console.log(input)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: That changes the data not the data type column.